# Solr query performance Issue

Tags: solr

I have 20 million records in the core, following solr query is taking more than 10 secs time, can anyone suggest how to improve the performance.

```
q=head:true AND domain:100 AND state:1 AND (type:text OR type:idoc)
&start=0
&rows=60
&df=metainfo
&fl=*,score
&sort=modified asc
```

Comment: show your schema.xml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.